# Typescript Pass Accessor Function from HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Hi I have a TypeScript Function which was pre defined like this :-

```
getClass(
  element: Element, 
  fieldAccessor: (element: Element) => string | undefined) {
  field = fieldAccessor(element);
  // Processing
  return class;
}
```

This is being called from HTML and the code definition is

```
<div>...
<span [ngClass]="getClass(element, (element) => element.field)">{{ element.field }}</span>
</div>
```

However I am getting the following error :-

> Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 43 in [getClass(element, (element) => element.multiplierType)] in /path/to/file.ng.html
>
> Parser Error: Unexpected token ')' at column 69 in [getClass(element, (element) => element.multiplierType)] in /path/to/file.ng.html

I think I my error is in the HTML definition. Any help to fix the call is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `fieldAccessor` is another function?

Comment: Hi I think the function getClass expects fieldAccessor function from the parameter. I thought passing "(element) => element.field" would work but it is not